# Reading in text document from a server

Tags: iphone, objective-c, parsing

I want to be able to store a text document on a server and then read this document when my app launches.

I would want to read e.g. a description for an object and item number, and a few urls to images and sound clips.

Is reading in and parsing a text document the best way to do it? If so how is it done?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can create any file you want on that server I would create a Property-List containing a NSDictionary. I think this will be the easiest way.

create the plist manually with the Property List Editor or programmatically with

```
- (BOOL)writeToFile:(NSString *)path atomically:(BOOL)flag
```

put it onto your server and read it in your application with

```
- (id)initWithContentsOfURL:(NSURL *)aURL
```